# How to Select with Max Value

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have an `Access` database which contains a `Grads` table :

```
Grads
 - studentId 
 - courseId 
 - tryNumber
 - semesterId 
 - finalGrad
```

How to get all info (`studentName, courseName, courseId, finalGrade`) from lines with max `tryNumber` (last try ) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want the one row with the `max` trynumber, then you should be able to use:

```
select g.studentid,
  g.courseid,
  g.trynumber,
  g.semesterid,
  g.finalgrade
from grads g
inner join
(
  select max(tryNumber) MaxTry
  from grads
) m
  on g.trynumber = m.maxtry
```

If you want to return each student with the `max(tryNumber)`, then you can use:

```
select g.studentid,
  g.courseid,
  g.trynumber,
  g.semesterid,
  g.finalgrad
from grads g
inner join
(
  select studentid, max(tryNumber) MaxTry
  from grads
  group by studentid
) m
  on g.trynumber = m.maxtry
  and g.studentid = m.studentid
```

Comment: No , I need all finalgrade

Comment: @MaathProgrammer Can you post some sample data and then the desired result?

Comment: Thanks  I will modify you query to work with me 
your query  is true Thanks   again

Comment: Your line "How to get all info (studentName, courseName, courseId, finalGrade) from lines with max tryNumber (last try ) ?" nowhere is telling that you need data per student.

Answer (score 0):

> This should work for you:

```
SELECT studentName, 
       courseName, couseId, 
       finalGrade, MAX(tryNumber) 
FROM grads
GROUP BY studentName, courseName, couseId, finalGrade
```

Comment: can not GROUP BY finalGrade , I need finalGrade with Max tryNumber

Comment: as in you need max of final grade??

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Select studentName, courseName, courseId, finalGrade From Grads
Where tryNumber=(Select MAX(tryNumber) From Grads)
```

Comment: This will return one row with max try number

Comment: Please elaborate you requirement. Do you need this per student?

Answer (score -1):

`select top 1 * from Grads order by tryNumber desc`